# Xcode crashed while renaming project - whole project broken

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I wanted to release an app I worked on and quickly change the project name. I usually duplicate projects before doing things like this but this time - because this procedure always worked on Xcode as I found it way more reliable than e.g. Eclipse - I didn't, which I immediately regretted.

Opened Xcode again and now I am seeing this [image]

I guess all the linking is gone now which is why Xcode doesn't "find" the files anymore. Renaming the remaining project stem to the old name gives

> couldn’t be moved to  because an item with the
>   same name already exists

and also manual renaming of folders won't work as the .xcodeproj is gone.

The project is written in Objective-C, and all the classes are still persistent, but the effort of adding all the xib's, referencing the outlets, setting architectures, etc will become the nightmare of my life. I do have a half-way recent backup but everything I did to make the app store-ready today will be gone.

Any ideas on how to rescue my project?

EDIT: What Xcode is now showing on the welcome screen is a project called "project" (literally) and it has the usual compass icon but with a white instead of a blue background referring to the path `<project folder>/<new project name>/` and below that "white" project there is a folder icon with the new name pointing to `<project folder>`.

I also made a snapshot before, of course it now says "Unable to read snapshots" in the "restore from snapshots" window.

Comment: This is what source control such as Git is for, it is build into Xcode, use it. They there is the TimeMachine backup, a remote repository such as the free BitBucket and possibly BackBlaze. None of these may seem important until after a loss, not is the time to implement these, do not wait until the next loss.

Comment: If it is showing you Apple LLVM error. Use -v to see invocation. Then you can try this. But first I would suggest you to always have a backup first. Now first backup your project in whatever form it is right now. And select the project name from where you change the name. After selecting it , Choose Targets and select yourAppName_Tests. Suppose CarTests. and in the Host Applications, select your app name that will display. Maybe this works for you.

Comment: Indeed as @simardeep states upon a castophy the first thing do to is not make any more changes and backup immediately. Attempts to recover may make recovery impossible. As an example: I accidently erased an SD card in my camera that had hundreds of new photos. I immediatly removed the card, slid the write-protect slider to read-only. Later I copied the card's content to disk and from there was able to recover all the images.

Answer (score 0):

Ok what I now did is renaming **ALL references from the old project name to the new one**. I even changed file names. I used Xcode's CMD+SHIFT+F and TextWrangler's "replace" function and thankfully I still had the .xcodeproj from yesterday's backup so from there I could copy it into the new project and rename stuff. There are still some things that don't work perfectly, for example auto layout doesn't "stretch" contents over the screen (it stays on iPhone 4s size, even on 6 plus simulator), I needed to set the scheme again and Launch Images / Icons got lost but I can look over that. The only thing I am afraid of now is that the final build might miss out a symbol or something like that so I eventually have a corrupt file in the App Store, but man it's a beta version, how much worse can it get anyway?

Thanks to everyone recommending me to **even backup the broken project**, I did this even before you said it but because I think it's a valuable advice I wanted to put it in my answer as well.

It's a shame that stuff like this can happen, I've been backing up my work on a daily basis and my project never got corrupted - until now.